# Can i add a parent record and a child record using the same _context.SaveChangesAsync()

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have the following 2 Parent/Child objects:-

```
 public Submission()
        {
            SubmissionQuestionSubmission = new HashSet<SubmissionQuestionSubmission>();
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string Npi { get; set; }
        public bool Independent { get; set; }
        public string Comment { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<SubmissionQuestionSubmission> SubmissionQuestionSubmission { get; set; }
    }


public partial class SubmissionQuestionSubmission
    {
        public int SubmissionQuestionId { get; set; }
        public int SubmissionId { get; set; }
        public string Answer { get; set; }

        public virtual Submission Submission { get; set; }
    }
```

and i created the following view model:-

```
 public class SubmissionCreate
    {
        public Submission Submission {set; get;}
        public IList<SubmissionQuestion> SubmissionQuestion { set; get; }

        public IList<SubmissionQuestionSubmission> SubmissionQuestionSubmission { set; get; }

    }
```

where i have the following action method to add a parent record (submission) and a child record (SubmissionQuestionSubmission ), but to do so, i have to issue 2 save requests to the database, one to save the parent and get its ID, while the other to save the child record and assign it the parent ID, as follow:-

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Create(SubmissionCreate sc)//Bind("Id,FirstName,LastName,Npi,Independent,Comment")]
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
              var newsubmission  =  _context.Submission.Add(sc.Submission);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                foreach (var v in sc.SubmissionQuestionSubmission)
                {

                    v.SubmissionId = sc.Submission.Id;
                    _context.SubmissionQuestionSubmission.Add(v);
                        }
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                TempData["message"] = "Thank You.. Your request has been submitted...";
                return View("Confirmation");
            }
            return View(sc);
        }
```

so my question is if i can do the above job, using one save statement instead of 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need use two `SaveChanges`. You can assign `newsubmission` into `Submission` property instead of `v.SubmissionId = sc.Submission.Id;`.

In this case `Id` and `ForeignKey` created automatically by **EF Core**

```cs
var newsubmission = _context.Submission.Add(sc.Submission);

foreach (var v in sc.SubmissionQuestionSubmission)
{
    v.Submission = newsubmission;
    _context.SubmissionQuestionSubmission.Add(v);
}
await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Another way

```cs
sc.Submission.SubmissionQuestionSubmission = new List<SubmissionQuestionSubmission>();
foreach (var v in sc.SubmissionQuestionSubmission)
{
    sc.Submission.SubmissionQuestionSubmission.Add(v)
}
_context.Submission.Add(sc.Submission);
await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
```